# Is it free to create container in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I would like to create containers for each virtual machine, then deploy them.
As I known `deploy` is not free.

Is it free to create container in Azure?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you mean by containers in this case. Docker containers in Azure container service?

Comment: No, `blob` containers in my `Storage account`

Comment: With blob containers, you pay for the storage space they require.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any official links about price? I would like to have more information

Comment: Martyn added a link to his answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Azure Storage, you only pay for consumption, measured in GB/month (e.g. less than a nickel/month per GB). Containers are essentially free, since they take up virtually zero data.

Comment: And by essentially, you need to keep in mind that the operation to create/destroy a container is considered a "billable transaction". $0.0036 per 100,000 transactions for Blobs

Comment: What is the difference between store 100gb in one container vs in two (50 gb in one and 50 gb in second)?

Comment: I mean what is the difference in price?

Comment: Zero difference in price, whether you store in one container or a thousand.

Comment: What is a "transaction"?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko please ask a new question, and not in comments. This isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

The pricing of Azure storage is based on consumption or how much you use. More information of the pricing can be found on the Azure [website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/).

Pricing also varies by region and by type of storage you provision.

Comment: What is the difference between store 100gb in one container vs in two (50 gb in one and 50 gb in second)?

Comment: Price wise nothing at all.